# Switch Azure Search to Solr using ARM Templates

Tags: arm-template

We are using Sitecore 9.0.1 in PAAS and i need to need switch from  Azure Search to Solr and i am following this blog

http://integryx.net/post/2018/05/05/switch-sitecore-9-from-azure-search-to-solr-step-by-step-instructions

There are two parts to it
1) Enable - Disable certain configuration files on MA-OPS ,MA-REP,xc-Collect
xc-Search,xc-Refdata 
2) Update config settings on CM,CD,Prc & Rep

We are not able enable and disable using ARM templates as files needs to downloaded first and then extension needs to be changes which is kind of manual step which we don't want

Can some body provide inputs on this.

Cheers
AT

Answer (score 2):

Changing search providers will require changes to many config files that were deployed as part of the [marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-au/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.AppSvc_SiteCore_IFrame) installation.

IMHO the best approach will be to deploy a fresh PAAS instance of sitecore that is configured to use Solr. We are using the [SIF framework](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework.aspx) for this and are in the process of building this into our continuous integration pipeline.

Alternatively, the [Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates) repo includes ARM templates for SC 9.1. If a solrConnectionString parameter is provided the templates will not create Azure Search resources and will configure sitecore to use Solr.

You'll need to stand up your own Solr server or preferably a SolrCloud cluster as neither SIF or the ARM templates deploy this for you. Remember that starting with SC9.1 Solr must have a HTTPS url.

Comment: Are there any ARM templates released by Sitecore to Provision Sitecore PAAS with Solr. If yes could could you provide the link.

Comment: Edited to include link to Sitecore ARM templates repo

Comment: https://github.com/GeekHive/SitecoreIaaSArmTemplates look for the "Solr VM" section if you want to deploy Solr with ARM templates to a VM.